# Component in React version 16

Tags: reactjs

The following is giving me an error in React v16.0. The error I'm getting is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined

```
import { React, Component } from 'react';

    class MyComponent extends Component {

       render() {

          return(
              <div>Hello World!</div>
          );
       };
    };
```

If I change it to the following, it works.

```
import React from 'react';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

   // Omitted for brevity
}
```

I'm aware of some changes from v15.x to 16.x but I'm not clear about this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your import needs to be the following: `import React, { Component } from 'react';`

`React` is your standard default export as before but `Component` is a named export.

Comment: I see! I guess we have to be much more careful and compliant with the rules now in v16.x. I always did `import { React, Component } from 'react'` in v15.x and it always worked.